# Saving a XML Document in another xml file

Tags: java, xml, dom

what's wrong? this code dont save and dont show error

this code :

1. read file menuAdm.xml
2. treat that Document
3. save treated content in another xml (menuAdm2.xml)

   ```
   DocumentBuilder dBuilder = null;
   try {
       dBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
       Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new File("/seguranca/menuAdm.xml"));


       System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
       Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();

       // do treatment of doc (menuAdm.xml)            

       // save into another file (menuAdm2.xml)
       TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
       Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
       DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
       StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("/seguranca/menuAdm2.xml") );
       transformer.transform(source, result);

   } catch (Exception e) {
       System.out.println("Error to save file " + e.getMessage());
   }
   ```

Comment: Please show how you are "treating" the doc object. And by "don't save", do you mean an empty .xml file, exactly same as original .xml, or no .xml is generated?

Comment: are you sure you have checked the location `"/seguranca/menuAdm2.xml"` properly? On windows this would mean something like `C:\seguranca\menuAdm2.xml`